# Can anyone identify the vintage bike frame on this single-speed?

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage

[image][image: Side view]

I want to know if anyone can identify this vintage bike frame. I really don't know much. It has a badge, but it just says [cycles limited].

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Front view] | [image: Back of headtube view] |

Answer (score 4):

Avon - see the following image search.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Avon Cycles Limited](https://avoncycles.com/) started in [1948 making brakes and saddles](https://avoncycles.com/pride).
Their current logo bears resembles the older version of the logo on the pictured bicycle.
[image]

[Head badge](https://www.flickr.com/photos/jschumacher/49255806643/in/pool-bicycleheadbadges/)
[image]

I could find nothing on their site that in any way resembled your bike.
I couldn't find any older bicycles, image search, vintage search etc., that resembled your bike.

The absence of a matching example does not prove the frame comes from a different maker but it does raise the question.

Comment: The shape and degree to which the head badge has been worn down makes me wonder whether it was intentional: Like the previous owner was (for example) named "Adam," found an Avon head badge, clipped a piece away, and attached it to the frame to be "their" bicycle.